# RSA key is not allowed

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, keychain, sshd

I can't configure SSH key-authentication on my new VDS server. After I've done `ssh-copy-id` I still get password prompt for user.

To debug I added `LogLevel DEBUG3` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and restarted `systemctl restart sshd` and saw in logs `/var/log/secure` this message:

> RSA key is not allowed

Why does this happen and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 6):

OpenSSH [disabled](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.7) RSA scheme by default for security reasons.

Therefore the best option is to create new local keys using more secure algo:

```sh
ssh-keygen -t ed25519
```